# What does the parenthesis operator does on its own in C++

Tags: c++

During writing some code I had a typo that lead to unexpected compilation results and caused me to play and test what would be acceptable by the compiler (VS 2010).

I wrote an expression consisting of only the parenthesis operator with a number in it (empty parenthesis give a compilation error):

```
(444);
```

When I ran the code in debug mode, it seems that the line is simply skipped by the program. What is the meaning of the parenthesis operator when it appears by itself?

Comment: Exactly the same as what it does in `(1+2)*3;`.

Comment: Something nobody's brought up which I think might be relevant is that the parentheses aren't needed; `444;` is equivalent. It calculates the value 444 and does nothing with it, or (since calculating 444 just to ignore it is a waste of time and doesn't do anything) the compiler can just skip it and not do anything.

Comment: Inside decltype, the parenthesis operator may have an influence: because it is always equivalent to the inner expression it avoids special decltype behaviors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I can answer informally,

```
(444);
```

is a *statement*. It can be written wherever the language allows you to write a statement, such as in a function. It consists of an *expression* `444`, enclosed in parentheses (which is also an expression) followed by the statement terminator `;`.

Of course, any sane compiler operating in accordance with the *as-if* rule, will remove it during compilation.

One place where at least one statement is required is in a `switch` block (even if program control never reaches that point):

```
switch (1){
case 0:
    ; // Removing this statement causes a compilation error
}
```

Comment: Is "informally" meant to be ironic? ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller: I'm too old (or too much of a charlatan; you decide...) to wheel out all the grammar elements from the standard.

Comment: I think you explained it splendidly with formal terms to boot. That's what me wonder :)

Comment: There is this thing though that `decltype(var)` and `decltype((var))` won't return the same type. Sometimes parenthesis by themselves transform a name into an expression.

Answer (score 0):

- `(444);` is a statement consisting of a  parenthesized expression `(444)` and a statement terminator `;`
- `(444)` consists of parentheses `()` and a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) expression `444`

> A parenthesized expression (E) is a primary expression whose type, value, and value category are identical to those of E. **The parenthesized expression can be used in exactly the same contexts as those where E can be used, and with the same meaning**, except as otherwise indicated.

So in this particular case, parentheses have no additional significance,
so `(444);` becomes `444`; which is then optimized out by the compiler.